# How to fix a gumbo

Tags: roux, gumbo

Embarrassingly, this NOLA transplant has messed up his gumbo. It seems like my roux didn't use enough flour so my gumbo has ribbons of roux instead of incorporating. Is there anything i can do to fix this? I feel like if i boil the sheen out of it or add a beurre manie it might fix it, but i also feel like i'm going screw up a dish at the same time

Comment: *NOLA transplant*? Please [edit] your question and explain what you are talking about.

Comment: @JanDoggen NOLA=New Orleans, Louisiana

Answer (score 2):

Strain out the solids and set them aside. Then, hit the liquid with a stick blender. You may also want to add a bit beurre manie or a bit of light roux if that doesn't work.